# How to assign id value from ng-repeat in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

```
<li class="item" style="margin-top:30%;" ng-repeat="a in result.result | filter: a.groupName=sortby"> 
          <input id="a.switchID" type="checkbox" ng-change="send(a.deviceID,a.pinNumber)" ng-model="value4 "></input>
          <label for="a.switchID"></label>
</li>
```

This is my html code, where i want to set value of id to value which is there in a.switchID, but I'm not able to call this element in controller. Is this a correct way?

Comment: Did you tried: <input id="{{a.switchID}}"

Comment: Thank you! I tried your solution. It's working. @CoderJohn

Comment: Posting it as answer ;)

Comment: Yeah sure :D @CoderJohn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried:

```
      `<input id="{{a.switchID}}" type="checkbox" ng-change="send(a.deviceID,a.pinNumber)" ng-model="value4 "></input>`
```